# Deep_search in big json object by method ruby

Tags: json, ruby, search, hash

I have a problem with filtering JSON object in ruby!
 1. My JSON object is a big array of two hashes.
 2. That hashes includes another hashes that include another arrays and hashes (oh god! :c).
My goal is to output Big hash that contains concrete value!
Examples down below:
JSON file just like in

```js
[#That's hash 0{
        "id": 0,
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "middleName": null,
        "email": "",
        "phones": [
            null,
            null
        ],
        "groups": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": ""
        }],
        "disabled": "",
        "technologies": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "",
            "children": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Farmer",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "fullName": ""
    },
 #That's hash1{
        "id": 0,
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "middleName": null,
        "email": "",
        "phones": [
            null,
            null
        ],
        "groups": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": ""
        }],
        "disabled": "",
        "technologies": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "",
            "children": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "",
                "children": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Not Farmer",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "fullName": ""
    }
]
```

Pseudocode on ruby (what I want to):

```rb
file = File.read("example.json") #=> Reading JSON file
data_hash = JSON.parse(file, object_class: Hash)  #=> Parsing JSON file

data = data_hash.filter #=> filter that hash if "technologies" is not empty!
data.get_hash_by_value(value) #=> For example i put "Not Farmer" in value, and that method must search in all data that (value) and output hash1 for me (because hash0 not include "Not Farmer")
```

That's big problem, i don't know what to do!!!
My thoughts is a recursive finding method..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own functions. Maybe it can help someone.

```rb
def check_children(item)
  return true if item["name"] == "Farmer"
  item["children"].each do |child_item|
    break if check_children(child_item)
  end
  return false
end

data_hash.each do |item|
  next if item["technologies"].empty?
  item["technologies"].each do |technologies_item|
    next if technologies_item["children"].empty?
    technologies_item["children"].each do |children_item|
      data << item if check_children(children_item)
    end
  end
end
```